# Convert postgresql trigger to mysql trigger

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I'm trying to transpose a postgres trigger to a mysql trigger. It automatically adds fields to the row according to the date added

```
CREATE FUNCTION convert_date ()
    RETURNS trigger
    AS $$

declare
    date_min DATE;
    date_max DATE;
    temp_year INTEGER;
begin
    SELECT SUBSTRING(NEW."dc_date_label",0,5)::integer
    INTO temp_year;

    SELECT  date(temp_year || '-01-10')
    INTO    date_min;

    SELECT  date(temp_year +1 || '-09-30')
    INTO    date_max;

    NEW."dc_date_start" = date_min;
    NEW."dc_date_end" = date_max;

    RETURN new;
end;

CREATE TRIGGER trig_b_i_compute_date()
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON campaigns
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE convert_date();
```

This is what i've done on mysql :

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER trig_b_i_compute_date
    BEFORE INSERT ON campaigns
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        DECLARE date_min DATE;
        DECLARE date_max DATE;
        DECLARE temp_year INTEGER;

    SET temp_year = SELECT CONVERT( SUBSTRING(NEW.dc_date_label,1,5), UNSIGNED INTEGER) ;
    SET date_min =  SELECT CONVERT( CONCAT(temp_year,'-01-10'), DATE);
    SET date_max =  SELECT CONVERT( CONCAT(temp_year + 1, '09-30'), DATE);

    SET NEW.dc_date_start = date_min;
    SET NEW.dc_date_end = date_max;


    END;
    //
DELIMITER ;
```

However I get an error :

```
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT CONVERT( SUBSTRING(NEW.dc_date_label,1,5), UNSIGNED INTEGER) ;
```

What is wrong with the procedure ?

Comment: Remove the @s..

Comment: still the same error

Comment: What is the data type of dc_date_label? And how does a value look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `SELECT` in a SET statement, you need to put it in parentheses:

```
SET temp_year = (SELECT ...);
```

But in your case you don't need a SELECT and you can just skip it:

```
SET temp_year = CONVERT(...);
```

You can also use the SELECT INTO syntax in MySQL:

```
SELECT CONVERT(...) INTO temp_year;
```

And there is no need to declare `date_min` and `date_max`. Also no need to cast everything explicitly. Your trigger body could be:

```
DECLARE temp_year INTEGER;

SET temp_year = CONVERT( SUBSTRING(NEW.dc_date_label,1,5), UNSIGNED);
SET NEW.dc_date_start = CONCAT(temp_year,     '-01-10');
SET NEW.dc_date_end   = CONCAT(temp_year + 1, '-09-30');
```

I don't know how `dc_date_label` looks like, and why the year should be 5 characters long. So I kept the year extraction as it is. But if it's a DATE, DATETIME or TIMESTAMP, you can just use the `YEAR` function:

```
SET temp_year = YEAR(NEW.dc_date_label);
```

And since it's much shorter, you could also use it inline and skip the `temp_year` variable:

```
SET NEW.dc_date_start = CONCAT(YEAR(NEW.dc_date_label),     '-01-10');
SET NEW.dc_date_end   = CONCAT(YEAR(NEW.dc_date_label) + 1, '-09-30');
```

And last one: Remove the semicolon after `END`. It might work, but it doesn't belong there.